# Why does this model not conform to Decodable? (a polymorphic JSON Christmas tale)

Tags: json, swift, swift-protocols, decodable

Hello `Codable` experts.

I want to decode incoming JSON for artists data. Two types of artists exist: individuals and bands.

Individuals are represented like this:

```
{
  "id":"123",
  "data":{
    "type":"individual",
    "firstName":"David",
    "lastName":"Bowie"
  }
}
```

while bands are represented like this:

```
{
  "id":"124",
  "data":{
    "type":"band",
    "name":"Queen"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to model this JSON *polymorphism* ( not sure this is the right word) in Swift like so:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Artist: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let data: ArtistData
}

enum ArtistType: String, Codable {
    case individual
    case band
}

protocol ArtistData: Decodable {
    var type: ArtistType { get }
}

struct IndividualArtistData: ArtistData, Codable {
    let type = ArtistType.individual
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}

struct BandArtistData: ArtistData, Codable {
    let type = ArtistType.band
    let name: String
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Type 'Artist' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'ArtistData' does not conform to 'Decodable'
```

I also tried a version where the `ArtistData` protocol was not inheriting `Decodable` and changing `Artist` definition to use protocol composition like so:

```
struct Artist: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let data: ArtistData & Decodable
}
```

but I get a similar error:

```
cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'Decodable & ArtistData' does not conform to 'Decodable'
```

How should I deal with this kind of scenario?

Happy holiday season.

Comment: I dont think this way is possible. You can either add all properties to one model and make optional those specific to band and artist. Or you can have custom initializer from decoder and first try to decode into one type and if that fails try decoding into another type

Comment: `ArtistData` itself doesn't conform to `Codable`. Types that conform to `ArtistData` conform to `Codable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` in `Artist` must be a concrete type or a generic constrained to `Codable`. It can't be a protocol.

My suggestion is to drop the protocol and declare an enum with associated types.

```
enum Artist : Decodable {
    case individual(String, IndividualArtist), band(String, BandArtist)

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case id, data }
    private enum ArtistKeys : String, CodingKey { case type }

    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws
    {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        let nestedContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ArtistKeys.self, forKey: .data)
        let type = try nestedContainer.decode(ArtistType.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
            case .individual:
                let individualData = try container.decode(IndividualArtist.self, forKey: .data)
                self = .individual(id, individualData)
            case .band:
                let bandData = try container.decode(BandArtist.self, forKey: .data)
                self = .band(id, bandData)
        }
    }
}

enum ArtistType : String, Decodable {
    case individual
    case band
}

struct IndividualArtist : Decodable {
    let type : ArtistType
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}

struct BandArtist : Decodable {
    let type : ArtistType
    let name: String
}
```

Comment: I built on your solution to build my final code. I am wrapping up a blog post about what I ended up doing since I was surprised this subject was relatively absent from my Google searches. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

As [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself), you are getting the error:

> cannot automatically synthesize `Decodable` because `ArtistData` does not conform to `Decodable`

`Codable` requires all the properties of the conforming type are of concrete type or constrained to `Codable` by means of generics. The type of the properties must be a full fledged type but not `Protocol`. Hence your second approach doesn't work out as you expected.

---

Though @vadian already posted an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59371854/3687801), I'm posting another approach which may be more inline with your thought process.

---

First, the `Artist` type should reflect the original payload data structure:

```
struct Artist: Codable {
    let id: String
    let data: Either<BandArtist, IndividualArtist>
}
```

Where the `Either` type is like:

```
enum Either<L, R> {
    case left(L)
    case right(R)
}
// moving Codable requirement conformance to extension
extension Either: Codable where L: Codable, R: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            // first try to decode as left type
            self = try .left(container.decode(L.self))
        } catch {
            do {
                // if the decode fails try to decode as right type
                self = try .right(container.decode(R.self))
            } catch {
                // both of the types failed? throw type mismatch error
                throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Either.self,
                                   .init(codingPath: decoder.codingPath,
                                         debugDescription: "Expected either \(L.self) or \(R.self)",
                                         underlyingError: error))
            }
        }
    }    

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case let .left(left):
            try container.encode(left)
        case let .right(right):
            try container.encode(right)
        }
    }
}
```

This should essentially solve your problem in the first place.

---

Now to extend this answer a little far, as I can see what you tried to achieve, where you deliberately tried to use constant value for the `type` of both `IndividualArtist` and `BandArtist`, you need to account for the **decoding** part manually. Otherwise the values of `type` properties here will be dumped by the **JSON** payload at the time of decoding (when the auto synthesized `init(from decoder: Decoder)` gets called). That essentially means, if the **JSON** is:

```
{
  "id":"123",
  "data":{
    "type":"individual",
    "name":"Queen"
  }
}
```

the `JSONDecoder` still will decode this as a `BandArtist` whereas this should not be the case as far as I understand like the way you are concerned. To tackle this, you need to provide custom implementation of `Decodable` requirement. (@vadian's answer account for this with the *nested container*)

Below is how you can do it from the types themselves:

```
struct IndividualArtist: Codable {
    let type = ArtistType.individual
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}
extension IndividualArtist {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let type = try container.decode(ArtistType.self, forKey: .type)
        guard self.type == type else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Payload doesn't match the expected value"))
        }
        firstName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        lastName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
    }
}

struct BandArtist: Codable {
    let type = ArtistType.band
    let name: String
}
extension BandArtist {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let type = try container.decode(ArtistType.self, forKey: .type)
        guard self.type == type else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Payload doesn't match the expected value"))
        }
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```